# Application crashes randomly when user taps on TextInputLayout

Tags: android

I get this crash message when user taps on `EditText` field of `TextInputLayout`

```
Crashed: main
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1174)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12717)
       at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6954)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:26066)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)



Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1174)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12717)
       at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6954)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:26066
```

Although there is no long click, the crash is random and i don't know any steps to reproduce it.

This is how i am adding the `TextInputLayout`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:theme="@style/SignUpEditTextTheme"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ic_email"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topGuideline">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_checkout_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:theme="@style/SignUpEditTextTheme"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/leftGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topGuideline" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_checkout_email);
inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
```

Comment: Start by removing one by one themes and styles for both and see if you get anything

Comment: Why do you constraint the EditText although it's wrapped inside the TextInputLayout which is constraint?

Comment: Could you post the code for the styles you use on `android:theme`?